# How to prevent rubocop to add a space after hash

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Rubocop changes `#!/usr/bin/ruby` to

```
# !/usr/bin/ruby
```

adds a space after the hash when I use `rubocop -a`, how can I avoid this

Comment: Which version of rubocop are you using?

Comment: I used the original version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to disable the `LeadingCommentSpace` cop. It ensures that there is a space between `#` and the text that follows it. Puts something like this in your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
LeadingCommentSpace:
  enabled: false
```

What you've stumbled upon is a bug, that I'll fix in the next RuboCop release (I'm its author). Obviously `#!` should be treated specially.

Comment: Btw, I cannot reproduce the problem with RuboCop 0.15. What version of RuboCop are you using?

Comment: gem list --local | grep ruboco
rubocop (0.15.0)

Comment: still it's an issue on rubocop 0.39.0 - `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`, `#!/usr/bin/env bundle exec rails runner`